# jQuery events on external objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem.
I'm looking for document-wide click events, but large chunks of my site is loaded through a div with an innerHTML object.

```
<div id="contentHolder">            
    <script>
        document.getElementById("contentHolder").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" id="content" data="article.html"></object>';      
    </script>
</div>
```

A listener like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", function (event){
    alert("Click");
 });
```

Only registers clicks on elements outside of the `ContentHolder`.
I realise that the loaded content probably has its own `document`.

Do any of you know of a way I can refer to this content inside the `Object`? :)
I read up on jQuery delegation, but it didn't seem to offer a solution to my problem.

I set up a semi-working example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwvJrW). It doesn't seem to allow loading external pages, understandably so - but the problem persists even without any actual loading. The example works locally.

## Edit

I solved the problem myself. Instead of using an `HTML Object` for a container, you can use jQuery append and the listeners will remain active not only from the sub-document's events but also the parent's.

```
$.get('document.html', function(result) {
     $('#container').append(result);
});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. Instead of using an `HTML Object` for a container, you can use jQuery append and the listeners will remain active not only from the sub-document's events but also the parent's.

```
$.get('document.html', function(result) {
     $('#container').append(result);
});
```

Comment: You should add your answer here, rather than in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#contentHolder').on('click', '.class-to-be-named', function() {
    // do your click stuff
});
```

It will bind the click event on `#contentHolder` and whenever you click within `#contentHolder` it will lookup if element `#contentHolder` was clicked, when is it calls the callback.